# Change value in xml using sed

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I have the following line in my xml file:

```
<domain-option name="security-domain" value="config2"/>
```

I should set new value using sed and it should not be dependent from current value. I mean instead of config2 can be any value which should be replaced with new one)

I'm tyring

```
sed -i '/<domain-option name="security-domain"/!b;n;cvalue=new-value/>' test.xml
```

but it creates new line, please help

Comment: Use an XML-aware tool to edit XML files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your xml file is guaranteed to provide your data on one line with this format, you should simply use `sed` `s` command (substitute) instead of your complex solution:

```
sed -r -i 's/(<domain-option name="security-domain" value=")([^"]*)/\1anotherval/' test.xml
```

I enable `-r` option to avoid escaping the parentheses. I create 2 groups and re-issue the first group and replace the second group (the old value) by a new one.

Note: If you need replacing by an env. variable you have to quit single quotes at some point

```
newval=the_new_value
sed -r -i 's/(<domain-option name="security-domain" value=")([^"]*)/\1'"$newval/" test.xml
```